# Does anyone know the history of the infinitive?

Tags: syntax, english, grammar, verbs, word-formation

I teach grammar, and I think it is no mystery to anyone that infinitives are strange.  I think it might help me to know the history of this verb-cum-noun-adjectiv

Comment: Are you wondering specifically about the English "to"-infinitive, or the concept of an infinitive in general across languages?

Comment: By "history" do you mean what the earlier source of infinitives is, or do you mean the history of how language-people think about infinitives (I don't think that infinitives are strange, but I probably have a different history with linguistic theory from yours).

Comment: Do you mean that you teach English (and its grammar), or that you teach linguistics? We ask all these questions to try to get background for the answer, and to find the range of what a useful answer might look like.

Comment: Also, along with all the other suggestions to edit, can you give some examples of what you find strange? (I'm not sure I under stand how the usual infinitives in any language are verbs followed by 'noun-adjectives'). Also, does [the wiki page on infinitives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive) not answer things for you?